# DRF Serializer How do I serialize my data and display

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have following Serializer I am facing problem with Json with serializing. I have user named daniel james and he have multiple subject like maths science I am providing nested serializer to fill all subject but based on subject users name also repeats below is more specific qsn

This is my model.

```
class Result(BaseModel):
    semester_choices = (
        ('first', 'First'),
        ('second', 'Second'),
        ('third', 'Third'),
        ('fourth', 'Fourth'),
        ('fifth', 'Fifth'),
        ('sixth', 'Sixth'),
        ('seventh', 'Seventh'),
        ('eight', 'Eight'),
        ('all', 'All'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    registration_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=semester_choices, null=True, blank=True)
    gpa = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

`serializers.py`

```
 class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = '__all__'

class ListResultSerializer(ResultSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField()
    semester = serializers.CharField()
    subject = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta(ResultSerializer.Meta):
    fields = (
        'user',
        'semester',
        'subject',
    )

def get_subject(self, instance):
    return SubjectSerializer(instance).data
```

This is my `SubjectSerializer`

```
class SubjectSerializer(ResultSerializer):
    class Meta(ResultSerializer.Meta):
        fields = (
            'gpa',
            'subject'
        )
```

And In my views.py I have done like this.

```
class ListResultView(rest_generics.ListAPIView, UserMixin):
    serializer_class = serializers.ListResultSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.get_user()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return usecases.ListResultUseCase(
            user=self.get_user()
        ).execute()
```

I use usecases.py to filter the data here is further code

```
class ListResultUseCase:
    def __init__(self, user: User):
        self._user = user

    def execute(self):
        self._factory()
        return self._result

    def _factory(self):
        self._result = Result.objects.filter(user=self._user)
```

Now this is the Json I am getting right now from above code.

```
[
    {
        "user": "daniel james",
        "semester": "first",
        "subject": {
            "gpa": "a+",
            "subject": "maths"
        }
    },
    {
        "user": "daniel james",
        "semester": "first",
        "subject": {
            "gpa": "A",
            "subject": "data structures"
        }
    }
]
```

I want my json to be in this format

```
 [
  {
    "user": "daniel james",
    "semester": "first",
    "subject": [
      {
        "gpa": "a+",
        "subject": "maths"
      },
      {
        "gpa": "A",
        "subject": "data structures"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any help in serializer?

Comment: can you share your models?

Comment: added have a look once @OpticPython

Comment: how do you want the response when you have multiple semesters?

Comment: Any solution ? do i need to change my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a seperate serializer to use with the nested serializer.

```
class SubjectNestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        exclude = ['user']
```

P.S

Try to change your model like this

```
class Semester(BaseModel):
    semester_choices = (
        ('first', 'First'),
        ('second', 'Second'),
        ('third', 'Third'),
        ('fourth', 'Fourth'),
        ('fifth', 'Fifth'),
        ('sixth', 'Sixth'),
        ('seventh', 'Seventh'),
        ('eight', 'Eight'),
        ('all', 'All'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='semesters')
    registration_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=semester_choices, null=True, blank=True)

class Subject(BaseModel):
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='semester_subjects')
    gpa = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer once check I have added SubjectSerializer inmy question.

Comment: you have duplicate data. it's hard to merge those without extra processing. would you consider seperating separating subject from Semester model. I'll add it above

Comment: Am I making my model correct? what shall I change?

Comment: check the above changes and see. so you can easily access the data through a nested serializer

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Serializer for your user, and adding a method field that retrieve all the subjects of the user like this.

```
def get_subjects(self,instace):
    subjects = Subject.objects.filter(user=instance)
    return SubjectSerializer(subjects, many=True)
```

Comment: I am still getting same Json no change

Comment: added have a look once

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an aggregation of existing data to have a more meaningful result for frontend. I'd rather generating my own response than using a serializer for this.

Here is a simple example for you.

## Let's say you want results for multiple users. (It's even easier if you want for one user)

```
def get_item_with_attribute_from_list(items, attribute, attribute_value):
"""
This is just a utility function that I use occasionally
"""
    if items is None or len(items) == 0:
        return None

    if isinstance(items[0], dict):
        for item in items:
            if item.get(attribute) == attribute_value:
                return item
    else:
        for item in items:
            if getattr(item, attribute, None) == attribute_value:
                return item

results = Result.objects.all().select_related('user')

response = []
for result in results:
    user_dict = get_item_with_attribute_from_list(response, "user", result.user.name)
    subject = {"gpa": "A", "subject": "data structures"}
    if user_dict:
        semester_list = user_dict['semesters']
        semester = get_item_with_attribute_from_list(semester_list, 'semester_name', result.semester)
        if semester:
            semester['subjects'].append(subject)
        else:
            semester_list.append({'subjects': [subject]})
    else:
        response.append({'user': result.user.name, 'semesters': [{'semester_name': result.semester, 'subjects': [subject]}]})
```

Resulting JSON will be something like this.

```
[
  {
    "user": "daniel james",
    "semesters": [
        {
            "semester_name": "first",
            "subjects": [
                
                {
                    "gpa": "a+",
                    "subject": "maths"
                },
                {
                    "gpa": "A",
                    "subject": "data structures"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "semester_name": "second",
            "subjects": [
                
                {
                    "gpa": "b+",
                    "subject": "geometry"
                },
                {
                    "gpa": "C",
                    "subject": "chemistry"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  },
  ... # Other user's data
]
```

This way, you'll have more structured data, you'll be able to calculate SPA's for each semester easily.

Comment: where do i place above method?

Comment: I always put `utils.py` to my apps for this kind of utility functions. You can place it there and then import it in your `views.py`

Comment: can you let me know how do i call your function in views

Comment: aggregating data in the backend works. but the best practice is avoid duplicates in the database and with django have minimal code and let the framework handle the burden for you. for this problem i think you could remodel data (after normalizing) and let the serializer do the aggregation would be best